# Sitecore Lucene Index not including all fields

Tags: lucene, indexing, sitecore, field

I created a new index which uses default database crawler. I can't get it to index all the fields on 5 templates that I specified.

I am using the IndexViewer module to check for the above fields. In the available fields, it lists all the fields that I want indexed but is only indexing the following fields - _url, _group, _name, and _tags.

I also wrote some code to test against the index fields and I am getting the desired results. I just need my index to include all the fields on the specified templates. Below is my configuration for the index.

```xml
<index id="Articles" type="Sitecore.Search.Index, Sitecore.Kernel">
<param des="name">$(id)</param>
<param des="folder">__articles</param> 
<Analyzer ref="search/analyzer"/>            
<locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
    <customindex type="Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler, Sitecore.Kernel">
        <Database>web</Database>
        <Root>/sitecore/content/[websitehome]</Root>
        <Tags>articles</Tags>
        <IndexAllFields>true</IndexAllFields>
        <include hint="list:IncludeTemplate">
            <template1>{C4663677-909E-4C4D-AB3E-78AADBB36CF7}</template1>
            <template2>{444D1797-1EA9-46F2-988D-2211CF926501}</template2>
            <template3>{1A859C38-FFFA-4102-BF7F-9E670495C3AF}</template3>
            <template4>{6EA89465-C6C4-4643-9589-188FBB180883}</template4>
            <template5>{52F0AB89-E9C3-4D10-9242-ACB669841C41}</template5>               
        </include>
    </customindex>              
    </locations>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [Lukeall](http://code.google.com/p/luke/downloads/detail?name=lukeall-3.5.0.jar) tool for observing index - IndexViewer may not show unstored fields. To use Lukeall just select the C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Sitecore\Data\indexes__articles folder, check "read-only" and "force unlock" and click OK.

Answer (score 1):

To make Lucene store index value - set ***storageType="YES"*** on field definition.

```
 <fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
        <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
          <field fieldName="_uniqueid" storageType="YES"
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. The index was including fields just not their values. Not sure if this is the desired functionality of the index but when I query against it, I get results back.

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us what you actually did to get it to work? I'm having this same issue right now and nothing I do is  working. Why aren't the values being included?

Comment: Are you not getting any results back when you perform a query? Can you see indexed items using Luke or indexviewer for Sitecore?

Comment: Have you gone through this checklist? This helped me resolve the above issues as well. http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2011/04/search-index-troubleshooting.html

Comment: I was using luke - it still wasn't showing all of the indexed fields, even though they were there. The problem ended up being that I was doing number queries, but not converting the numbers to lucene's linear string representation of them, so no results were being returned.

Comment: I think in Sitecore implementation of Lucene you have to specify to "STORE" the fields and that is when you will see values in those fields. Luke will show you the fields but not their values for this reason.